Piercer Feat with Sneak Attack and Critical
So my rogue/ranger is facing a problem with a crit atm.

When you score a critical hit that deals piercing damage to a creature, you can roll one additional damage die when determining the extra piercing damage the target takes.

I have crit with sneak attack, does that mean I double my bow damage and sneak attack damage, and then add on an additional dmg dice for each type? Looking something like this:
Bow crit + Sneak attack crit + piercer dice to both.
2d8+4d6+1d8+1d6
Or do I have to choose from which one I want the dice to go to?

“You roll one additional damage die”
It isn’t entirely clear to me where you’re getting the idea that you might roll one additional die of each type, as the feature states:

When you score a critical hit … roll one additional damage die

Without saying anything about types of dice. Just one die. So any interpretation that involves rolling two or more additional die is out. One critical hit, one additional die.
Now, the question remains, “which type of die do I roll when the attack’s damage has multiple types?” For this, there is no other rule or guidance to be found, so the only thing we can say is “just pick one”. So to answer the question via a dice formula:

2d8 + 4d6 + 1d8

Breaking this down now:

1d8 base bow damage
2d6 base sneak attack damage
1d8 critical hit bow damage
2d6 critical hit sneak attack damage
1d8 of “one additional damage die”


Okay, thank you very much for the input. It is appreciated.

Also, i think its worth mentioning that the additional damage must be pierce type. So it is ok for SA, since it has the same damage type of the weapon, but not ok for other additional damage dice, like poison or divine smite, for example.
